# Python: Is it possible to add new methods to the Tuple class

Tags: python, tuples

In Python, is it possible to add new methods to built-in classes, such as Tuple. I'd like to add 2 new methods: first() returns the first element of a tuple, and second() returns a new tuple without the first element.

So for example:

```
x = (1, 2, 3)

x.first()   # 1
x.second()  # (2, 3)
```

Thanks

Comment: No, you must create your own class.  (You can subclass tuple.)

Comment: Why don't you just slice the tuple? first is `t[0]` and "second" is `t[1:]`.

Comment: So python classes are closed and cannot be extended like in Ruby or C#. Is that correct? I'm new to python, so just want to know what can and can't be done. Being able to extend existing classes without altering their default behaviors can be very useful. An example is LINQ was mostly implemented with extension methods.

Comment: @user1797036 No. Classes implemented in C (which is true of most builtin classes) cannot be monkeypatched. However, they can be extended by inheritance.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, but **don't**.

There exists a [dark and dangerous forbiddenfruit](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit) that unsafely and dangerously allows such a thing. But it's a dark place to go.

Rather, you can make a new class:

```
class MyTuple(tuple):
    def first(self):
        return self[0]

    def second(self):
        return self[1:]

mt = MyTuple((1, 2, 3, 4))

mt.first()
#>>> 1
mt.second()
#>>> (2, 3, 4)
```

Preferably you can create an actual linked list that doesn't require copying every time you call this.

Preferably, don't do that either because there are almost no circumstances at all to want a self-implemented or singly-linked-list in Python.

Comment: This is the same as my answer, and BrenBarn's comment, only later, and with less explanation.

Comment: Python has a standard linked datastructure: `deque`

Comment: You don't cover actually modifying the built-in class, though, which I thought was a relevant (if not useful) addition.

Comment: Neither do you. forbiddenfruit doesn't actually alter the class; it creates a wrapper, and alters the binding of the global name.

Comment: "forbiddenfruit doesn't actually alter the class". I'm very dubious of that claim.

Comment: Which I did. What makes you think the builtin isn't modified? What do you think happens? Actually, I've thought of a way to test this. Wait a mo. // And I'm right. The `id` of `str` is the same before and after the patch, hence it is the same object. I wasn't snarky to you, please don't be to me.

Comment: What makes me think the builtin isn't modified is that there is no part of the code which modifies any builtin object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37794/discussion-between-veedrac-and-marcin)

Comment: Unless you add `__slots__` to your class its instances have a unnecessary `__dict__` instance.

Answer (score 3):

No. You could use a `namedtuple` to introduce names for various positions; or you could subclass tuple; or you could simply write functions. There's nothing wrong with a function.

However, absolutely none of these are a good idea. The best idea is just to write code like everyone else: use subscripts and slices. These are entirely clear, and known to everyone.

Finally, your names are highly misleading: first returns the first element; second returns a tuple composed of the second and third elements.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'd feel much better about that.

Comment: Or more directly, `second` returns everything but the first element.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Does it? Do we know that?

Comment: _"and second() returns a new tuple without the first element."_

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Apparently we do.